# Handle all rotations for dynamic view in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I've created a `runtime image view` and added `subviews` to it (just `like splash screen` concept). Now i've to handle all 4 rotations for my iPad but what is the approach for it?

My code snippet:

```
    UIView *mainScreen = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]window];        
    UIView *windowBlocker = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:mainScreen.frame];
    windowBlocker.tag = 999;
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(165, 200, 450, 480)];        
    imageView.layer.backgroundColor=[[UIColor colorWithRed:248/255 green:248/255 blue:248/255 alpha:0.5] CGColor];
    imageView.alpha = 0.6;

    imageView.layer.cornerRadius=10;
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    [windowBlocker addSubview:imageView];
```

This below approach would be painful to set each subview's co-ordinate for each rotation. isn't it?
How to handle the rotation here. I have to disable auto layout also for scrolling purpose.

```
-(void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
        NSLog(@"Landscape left");
        self.lblInfo.text = @"Landscape left";
    } else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        NSLog(@"Landscape right");
        self.lblInfo.text = @"Landscape right";
    } else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
        NSLog(@"Portrait");
        self.lblInfo.text = @"Portrait";
    } else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        NSLog(@"Upside down");
        self.lblInfo.text = @"Upside down";
    }
}
```

pls guide.
Thanks

Comment: if your view is a subview of a view inside a view controller your view frame will be update automatically on rotation (assuming your view controller declares it supports rotation)

Comment: you generally don't have to deal with window objects directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIView *mainScreen = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]window];
UIView *windowBlocker = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:mainScreen.frame];
windowBlocker.tag = 999;
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(165, 200, 450, 480)];
imageView.layer.backgroundColor=[[UIColor colorWithRed:248/255 green:248/255 blue:248/255 alpha:0.5] CGColor];
imageView.alpha = 0.6;

imageView.layer.cornerRadius=10;
imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
[windowBlocker addSubview:imageView];

    [[[mainScreen subviews] objectAtIndex:0] addSubview:windowBlocker];
```

Comment: _window is your main screen

Comment: Thats superb. I missed to add it as the subview to main screen. Also can you set up struts and spring for the control in code? any idea.